# Java DrawRect Problems

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a FileManager using Java. I need to add rectangle selection to my program, the same way it works in windows (in order to select multiple files within a rectangle).
My problem is that whenever I add a layout to my DrawRect panel to place Icons, I cannot draw the rectangle any more!
This is my DrawRect code:

```
   import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawRect extends JPanel {

    int x, y, x2, y2;

//    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        JFrame f = new JFrame("Draw Box Mouse 2");
//        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        f.setContentPane(new DrawRect());
//        f.setSize(300, 300);
//        f.setVisible(true);
//    }

   public DrawRect() {
        x = y = x2 = y2 = 0; //
        MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);
    }

    public void setStartPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setEndPoint(int x, int y) {
        x2 = (x);
        y2 = (y);
    }

    public void drawPerfectRect(Graphics g, int x, int y, int x2, int y2) {
        int px = Math.min(x,x2);
        int py = Math.min(y,y2);
        int pw=Math.abs(x-x2);
        int ph=Math.abs(y-y2);
        g.drawRect(px, py, pw, ph);
        g.fillRect(px,py,pw,ph);

    }

    class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            setStartPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            setEndPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            setEndPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int alpha = 50; // 50% transparent
        Color myColour = new Color(0, 0, 200,50);
       g.setColor(myColour);
        drawPerfectRect(g, x, y, x2, y2);

    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnS8l.png)

To explain more, In the picture above I have a SplitPane which its right part is a ScrollPane that An instance Of DrawRect is added to that scroll pain, And Icon's Also added to my DrawRect panel with Multiple rows of Grid Layout in each there is a flow layout.
What can I do so that I can draw Rectangle ?

As you can see below, If I don't add any layout to my DrawRect panel it works fine but still misses the parts where Icons and so Layouts exist:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI9p0.png)

And finally, I have one question: After I fixed this problem, I can I tell buttons within this selection rectangle to be selected? 
Thanks a lot!

===========================================================================
Update:

```
   import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

abstract public class GridIcon extends JButton {
    private Color pressedBackgroundColor = Color.blue;
    private String shortenedName;
    private String path;
    private boolean setSelected = false;


    public GridIcon(String text, Icon icon, String path) {
        this.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        this.path = path;

        if (text.length() > 9) {
            shortenedName = text.substring(0, 9);
            shortenedName += "...";
        } else
            shortenedName = text;

        this.setIcon(icon);
        this.setText(shortenedName);
        this.setFocusable(false);


        this.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        this.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        super.setOpaque(false);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        super.setBorderPainted(false);
        super.setBorder(null);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));


        //  super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,60));

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isPressed() || setSelected) {
            g.setColor(pressedBackgroundColor);
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentAreaFilled(boolean b) {
    }


    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public Color getPressedBackgroundColor() {
        return pressedBackgroundColor;
    }

    public void setPressedBackgroundColor(Color pressedBackgroundColor) {
        this.pressedBackgroundColor = pressedBackgroundColor;
    }

    public void setSetSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        setSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public boolean isSetSelected() {
        return setSelected;
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (setSelected)
                setSelected = false;

            else
                setSelected = true;

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for how painting is done.

What happens is that components added to the panel are painted AFTER your selection rectangle is painted.

The solution is to override `paint(...)` with your custom code. Then the selection rectangle will be painted on top of the child components.

Comment: I don't get it. I read things you sent me but it's too complicated that I cannot solve it. I don't know how to tell it to paint the buttons added to it later :(

Comment: Based on your original question I gave you a simple suggestion. The suggestion was to override `paint()` instead of paintComponent() on the "panel" so that the selection rectangle is painted after the buttons are painted. If it doesn't help then I don't understand the question.

Comment: THANKS A LOT  camickr  , YOU SAVED ME MAN!!! IT W-O-R-K-S !!! I was dealing with it for a week !!!